# MS OAuth2 on Android blank page in login webview -- if I break config, it will display the error in the webview and work

Tags: android, webview, oauth-2.0, nativescript, nativescript-oauth2

I have a nativescript project and attempting to login using Oauth2.0. Now on iOS, everything works fine. In Android, whenever I click on login the webview is blank white, no error nothing on the console either.

- if I copy-paste the 'url' of the webview for the authorization and
  take it on my desktop's browser -- all is good and it works
- If I break the configuration of the request by either removing "scopes" or putting gibberish on the redirectURI, the webview displays the microsoft page with an error of what broke.
- Tried Pie and Oreo on Nexus 5 + Pixel XL2
- Updated Chrome/Webview to the latest version
- Implemented custom URI schema for both Android and iOS following nativescript-oauth2 plugin guidelines.
- Tested the webview to make sure it works with other sites

I've been trying things out and pretty much stuck on this for over 3 days now :(

In app manifest for the scheme:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Custom Path data -->
            <data android:path="/auth" 
            android:scheme="msala1ea6c64-3d77-4f2b-9baf-1cf72da2d376"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

And of course there's the 'android:launchMode="singleTask">`

Oauth2 Config:

```
`openIdSupport: 'oid-full',
        clientId: 'a1ea6c64-3d77-4f2b-9baf-1cf72da2d376',
        redirectUri: 'msala1ea6c64-3d77-4f2b-9baf-1cf72da2d376://auth',
        urlScheme: 'msala1ea6c64-3d77-4f2b-9baf-1cf72da2d376',
        scopes: ['openid', 'https://outlook.office.com/mail.read']`
```

and `msala1ea6c64-3d77-4f2b-9baf-1cf72da2d376://auth` is registered in Azure as a redirectURI

Comment: Is it possible for you share the code of html where you are loading webview?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I got the same exact problem.

Comment: Sadly no, ended up giving up on NativeScript at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!